# Python messagebox exception handling

Tags: python, exception, tkinter, sqlite3-python

I have been working on a python project using sqlite3, which allows the user to update, delete, and search for a data in database. For the selection process, the user is asked to choose the column name from the database table according to which selection would be done. I am choosing the column and typing the value for which I want to search, but the program message box shows exceptional error.T he database name is `criminal_records`.

How should I update the code to cope with the exception?

```py
def search_data(self): 
    if self.var_search.get()=="":
        messagebox.showerror('Error','Please enter a search term')
    else:
        try:
            conn=sqlite3.connect('criminal_records.db')
            my_cursor=conn.cursor()
            my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM criminal_records WHERE "+str(self.var_com_search.get())+" LIKE '%"+str(self.var_search.get()+"'%"))
            rows=my_cursor.fetchall()
  
            if len(rows)!= 0:
                self.criminal_table.delete(*self.criminal_table.get_children())
                for i in rows:
                    self.criminal_table.insert('',END,values=i)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except Exception as es:
            messagebox.showerror('Error',f'Due to{str(es)}')
```

[image: how it looks.]

Comment: Try: `my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM criminal_records WHERE ? LIKE '%?'%", (self.var_com_search.get(), self.var_search.get()))`

Comment: And I just realized that I just made the error myself, you need to put the last `%` into the `'`s, like: `'%?%'`

Comment: Assign the SQL statement to a variable and print the value of that variable to see whether the final SQL statement is correct or not.

Comment: It is showing the error again"Due to incomplete number of bindings,1 supplied out of 2"

Answer (score 0):

If you save the final SQL statement to a variable and print it out:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM criminal_records WHERE "+str(self.var_com_search.get())+" LIKE '%"+str(self.var_search.get()+"'%")
print(sql)
```

You will get (based on your provided image):

```
SELECT * FROM criminal_records WHERE Case ID LIKE '%12789250'%
```

The above SQL statement has two issues:

- column name `Case ID` not quoted
- last `%` is not within the single quoted string

It is better to use *placeholder* for the search string (note that you cannot use placeholder on column name) and embed the column name within double-quotes:

```py
sql = f"""SELECT * FROM criminal_records WHERE "{self.var_com_search.get()}" LIKE ?"""
my_cursor.execute(sql, (f"%{self.var_search.get()}%",))
```

Note that the value of `self.var_com_search` comes from pre-defined values of a combobox widget which does not cause SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I was able to fix the code, and it's now running smoothly.